# Is Twilio status callback url (webhook) synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: twilio, webhooks

I have a question for the community here since I could not find a clear answer in the Twilio's docs.
Basically I've setup a Messaging Service and specified a status callback url:
[image]

Will Twilio POST do this url in a synchronous manner? Is it safe to assume that consecutive calls to this url will happen only after a previous request is anwsered by my server?

I'm afraid of a race condition here - that the first POST could be handled 
 after the second one and I could update the message in my db with an outdated status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Webhooks are usually always asynchronous, and this is also the case with Twilio.

While we will queue things like outbound phone calls or SMS messages, we will make webhook requests as many times as we can to your server. Anything outside of that would make the webhooks way less "real-time" than they actually already are.

If you're looking to avoid race conditions though, I would suggest implementing that in your application, which you can do by checking the SID for that request or the SID for that message.

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

it's asynchronous, and it's a common mechanism to get the status of the async process.